# How to redirect store to update method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to redirect `store` to `update` method? I tryed the following code:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    return $this->update(new Product, $request);
}

public function update(Product $product, ProductRequest $request)
{

    // code

}
```

However, the first parameter of `update` need an already in database user and the above code does not work as expected. (it update the entire users in db!)

What is the correct way to achieve that?

```
    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->maintain(new User, $request);
    }

  public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->maintain($user, $request);
    }

  private function maintain($user, $request)
    {
    //code;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using route model binding for the update method?

Comment: @Iamzozo yes. I use it.

Answer (score 0):

The model for the update method could be the problem, your code is okay for this part:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $this->update(new Product, $request);
}

public function update(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $product->fill($request->all())->save();
    // code
}
```

For example, with route model binding:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::model('products', App\Product::class);
```

Or with a custom binding:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::bind('products', function($param) {
   return Product::where('slug', $param)->first();
});
```

Make sure you are not using `get()` in custom binding, it will pass back a collection.